# How to use DataContractSerializer to deserialize a single value in root node?

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, datacontractserializer

Suppose I want to deserialize the following XML using  DataContractSerializer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>               
<ServerName>abcde</ServerName>
```

The following data structure doesn't work for me, but I can't think of a way to do this:

```
[DataContract(Name = "ServerName", Namespace = "someNamespace")]
public class ServerName
{

}
```

Is DataContractSerializer able to handle this situation at all? If not, I will have no choice but to stream XML directly. Thanks!